# How to add a notification message to validate view model data in the controller POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, notifications

I'm trying to add a `notification message` based on if there is an `error` with the `input` from the client side.

The problem is that I don't know where to put the `message code` if the client doesn't enter in correct details and I **HAVE** tried placing it in different sections of my `code method` where I thought it would make sense.

I know how to do it **without** a `ViewModel` because you just make use of the `Model.IsValid` if statement. So that's what I did on certain `controllers` where I didn't make use of a `ViewModel`. I've also tried adding a  `Model.IsValid` if statement in the code with the `ViewModel` but that didn't work either.

I was able to put the `success message` in the right place, but wherever I put the `error message` it seems to still come up simultaneously with the `success message`, which is incorrect. It's actually supposed to pop up if the client doesn't `select` or  enter's in something wrong, preventing a successful creation`.

This is my code for the `POST` method where I use the `ViewModel`:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(DeliveryVM model)
        {
            Delivery delivery = new Delivery()
            {
                DriverID = model.DriverID,
                Created_Date = DateTime.Now,
                Created_Time = DateTime.Now
            };

            db.Deliverys.Add(delivery);
            db.SaveChanges();
            // save the selected orders based on the ID of the Delivery object
            IEnumerable<int> selectedOrders = model.Orders.Where(o => o.IsSelected).Select(o => o.ID);
            foreach (int ID in selectedOrders)
            {
                Order order = db.Orders.Where(o => o.OrderID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
                order.DeliveryID = delivery.DeliveryID;
                db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;

            }

            var driver = from ord in db.Drivers where ord.DriverID == delivery.DriverID select ord;


            foreach (Driver ord in driver)
            {

                    ord.DriverStatus = "Unavailable";
            }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            Success(string.Format("Delivery No: {0} was successfully created!", delivery.DeliveryID), true);
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = delivery.DeliveryID });
        }

        // Error
        Danger("Oh Snap! Looks like something went wrong!", true);
        return View(model);

        }
```

Notice that `Success(string.Format("Delivery No: {0} was successfully created!", delivery.DeliveryID), true);` is placed correctly.

With `Danger("Oh Snap! Looks like something went wrong!", true);` it doesn't matter where I place it, it still pops up after the `Delivery` has been `created` and not when there's an `error`. I explain why I thought I should place where I did, in the code snippet, but I was wrong.

Can anyone help me out with where to put the `error message` so that it pops up when there's a `error` because the user didn't select any values or entered in the incorrect details?

View:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DriverID, "Driver Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DriverID, Model.DriverList, "-Please select-", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DriverID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What do you `Success()` and `Danger()` methods do?

Comment: They display a notification after something has been created or if validation was unsuccessful.

Comment: Yes but what are they doing? Adding `ModelState` errors? Adding some message to `ViewBag` or a model property? You need to show them.

Comment: I followed this tutorial to implement them, http://jameschambers.com/2014/06/day-14-bootstrap-alerts-and-mvc-framework-tempdata/ - So I think it adds some message to a viewbag property then displays it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I'm not sure what to code to add in the question so that's why I included the link to the tutorial I used so you can see the way I created the messages.

Comment: Based on you latest edit you have it in the correct place (just before you return the view, but I have no idea if you have implemented it correctly (or even implemented it all in that view) so impossible to help. And its using `TempData` (not `ViewBag`). But why would you do this anyway (forcing the user to dismiss a dialog and displaying a message that does not even inform the user of the errors?)

Comment: And why are you doing all that work before you even check if `ModelState` is valid. If its not, then its just a waste of resources and you have already saved the `Delivery` even if its invalid!

Comment: It works with the success message and it works on every other controller where I didn't use the `ViewModel`. Also, I'm referring to when the user tries to select a driver for instance, and the user doesn't select a driver, the creation won't proceed. So I want to display that error message when that happens..

Comment: Then just use the inbuilt validation system. Add validation attributes to your properties, for example `[Required]` and in the view include `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.yourProperty)` The framework will do it all for your. But that's not what your doing anyway because you already save `Delivery` to the database even if its invalid - you do that before you even check `if (ModelState.IsValid)`

Comment: I already use the inbuilt validation, I've included the view code in my question to show you that I do. What I want to do is display an error message string alongside that validation error.

Comment: Why? - a message stating "Please select a driver" is self explanatory. Adding  "Oh Snap! Looks like something went wrong!" to it is just confusing (especially when something DID NOT go wrong). What is the point of this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Use Modelstate is valid

if(modelstate.isvalid()){
     viewbag.sucess="data entered sucessfully"
    }
    else{
         viewbag.error="somerhing went wrong";
    }

 use that or call viewbag.success or viewbag.error on view where you want to use thanks maybe it will help for you
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the proper way to check validation is via:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // Success
    // Save or whatever
    return RedirectToAction("Foo");
}

// Error
return View(model);
```

That way, you never even attempt to save, unless validation is successful. Also, it's very easy at glance to see where an error message vs. a success message should be sent.

Second, even if what you had could work, you have to consider how the code is being run. First, `Danger` is called, and it's *always* called, whether the save will eventually be successful or not. Then you attempt to save. In the case where the save is successful, you've already called `Danger` so you get the error message *and* the success message. In the case where the save fails, then a 500 error is generated, meaning processing is then handed off the the error handler to show a generic server error message, the content of 500.html or whatever custom action you have handling 500s. Regardless, the fact that you called `Danger` is long lost.

You *could* catch the exception and then respond accordingly:

```
try
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
except (DbEntityValidationException)
{
    Danger("Oh Snap! Looks like something went wrong!", true);
    return View(model);
}
```

But, then, you're hitting the DB needlessly. It's far better to use the built-in model validation available to you with `ModelState.IsValid`.

Comment: I've edited the code with what you suggested, and still doesn't bring up the danger message if the user doesn't select or enter data on the form. I've edited my question above, to show you how I added it. Maybe I did it wrong?

Comment: You're saving the delivery before you're checking whether the ModelState is valid. Move all your action logic that should happen if there's no error into this `if` block.